# Can a parent know the current iteration of its child ForEach

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way for a container of a ForEach to know its current iteration. I have thought about this for a while and all I can come up with having each item be a button that when tapped will  change some state.. but is that the only way??

I fear this may be a complex solution

[[image: Video thumbnail]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Parent View")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Text("Is there a way for the parent view to know which object in child ForEach to know what item is on screen?").bold()
                .padding()
                .padding(.horizontal)
            Spacer()
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<10) { object in
                        ZStack {
                            Text(object.description)
                                .font(.custom("", size: 50))
                            Circle()
                            .stroke()
                            .frame(width: 370)
                                .padding()
                        }
                        
                    }.padding()
                }
            }
            Text("Currently showing   ??  ")
            Text("How to increment this number with current item in view")
                .padding()
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're using a ScrollView, you can use a [ScrollViewReader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewreader)

Comment: @EmilioPelaez From what I read, a reader only supports programmatic scrolling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to read container and scrolled item view frames and update counter state depending on intersection fraction.

Here is a demo. Prepared with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var current = 0

    @ViewBuilder
    var header: some View {    // to simplify body
        Text("Parent View")
            .font(.largeTitle)
        Text("Is there a way for the parent view to know which object in child ForEach to know what item is on screen?").bold()
            .padding()
            .padding(.horizontal)
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    var footer: some View {    // to simplify body
        Text("Currently showing \(current)  ")
        Text("How to increment this number with current item in view")
            .padding()
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gp in
            VStack {
                header
                Spacer()

                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    HStack(spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(0..<10) { object in
                            ZStack {
                                Text(object.description)
                                    .font(.custom("", size: 50))
                                Circle().stroke()
                                    .padding()
                            }
                            .frame(width: gp.size.width)
                            .background(GeometryReader { sp -> Color in
                                let bounds = sp.frame(in: .global)
                                let frame = gp.frame(in: .global)

                                // tune factor as you need
                                if frame.intersection(bounds).size.width > frame.size.width * 0.55 {
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        current = object
                                    }
                                }
                                return Color.clear
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }

                footer
            }
        }
    }
}
```