# Performance problems stemming from GeometryReader & ViewModel

Tags: swiftui

I'm having some serious performance problems.

Here is what I know:

- The performance problems only started after I added a parent GeometryReader and a child Geometry Reader. I did this so I could read the current value of the ScrollView. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66590706/can-a-parent-know-the-current-iteration-of-its-child-foreach/66594664#66594664) is that concept, isolated:
- The problem is not from GeometryReader by itself but the intersection method:
  [image]

I am calling that here:

```
 View()
.background(GeometryReader { child -> Color in
                                    let bounds = child.frame(in: .global)
                                    let frame = parent.frame(in: .global)
                                    
                                    if frame.intersection(bounds).size.width > frame.size.width * 0.55 {
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            vm.selectedMovie = movie
                                        }
                                    }
                                    return Color.clear
                                })
```

> The purpose of that method is to update a class property when the frame gets to a certain position.

Here is a demo of how it is used and performance:

[image: demo]

> Relevant Code

```
GeometryReader { parent in <-- RootView 
  ...
    ZStack{...}.background(GeometryReader { child in 
       //This is where the intersection method I posted above is called
```

What can I do to improve performance?? (Let me know if I left out any important details)

Comment: can you explain about **GeometryReader { child -> Color in** normally I use like **GeometryReader { geometry in** what is this **child -> Color**?

Comment: You've probably created a loop with `vm.selectedMovie = movie` updating the state. My guess is that it will be impossible to provide a suggestion for improving performance unless you can show enough code for a reproducible example.

Comment: GeometryReader is of type (GeometryProxy) -> Content, so most times you would not need to declare a return type because when using it in SwiftUI view they will automatically return the view. But here we are using it in a `.background` that has components that aren't views i.e. the stored properties, so for it to compile a return type needs to be declared, in this case it is Color

Comment: @jnpdx I'll work on that